# Batch Program to copy into another folder and make a text file from the copied files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to make a batch program that will copy all files from a folder destination that I tell it to in the program and list all the files that are in that folder in a text file so that the program that I am building can read the text file. I have the batch program to already copy all the files into the folder that I need, all that is left is to have it make the text file.

Here's what I have right now

```
@echo off
setlocal
set source=c:\My Folder 
set dest=C:\Copied folder
pushd "%source%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /s 2^>NUL') do copy "%%a" "%dest%
popd
```

I changed the source and dest locations for privacy reasons.
I just need to know what and where I need to put in the line that will tell it to read all the files that it copied and put them into a text file.

Thanks in Advanced!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. The `list` variable stores the file path for list of copied files.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set source=c:\My Folder 
set dest=C:\Copied folder
set list=c:\copied files.txt
pushd "%source%"
echo>nul 2>"%list%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /s 2^>NUL') do (
  echo %%~dpa%%~nxa >>"%list%"
  copy "%%a" "%dest%"
)
popd
```

Comment: I tried it and I don't think it's making the text file. When I copied the files I did a pause so I could see what it was doing and here is what it said

     1 file(s) copied
   Access is denied.

I did just leave 'set list=c:/copied files.txt' alone and didn't do anything with it.

Comment: I've edited the code since it's missing surrounding quote for the `%list%` variable to fix wrong output file path (it previously saves to "c:\copied" instead of "c:\copied files.txt". Also change the `list` path since by default, a user don't have write access to root folder (thus gives "access denied" error). And/or change `dest` path also as needed to make sure it points to a writeable and already exist folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just add...

```
DIR /b /a-d "%dest%" > copied_files.txt
```

...at the end of your original script.

**Edit:** I was a little bit confused by the `pushd`/`popd` commands, I've seen those before, but I have never used them. Now reading up on [ss64](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) about it, I'd like to suggest you drop those and just put the path into the `FOR`'s `DIR` command. So it comes together like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set source=c:\My Folder
set dest=C:\Copied folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /s "%source%" 2^>NUL') do copy "%%a" "%dest%
dir /b /a-d "%dest%" > copied_files.txt
```